# Working Rhino code with Java 1.7 and make Exeception with Java 1.8

Tags: java, java-8, rhino, retrotranslator

My application use Rhino to mix javascript code and Java objects.

Every things work great with JVM 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7, but generate a bad ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using JVM 1.8.0 at runtime:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

public class RhinoOn8 {

    static public void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {        
        Context ctx = Context.enter();
        Scriptable scope = ctx.initStandardObjects();
        Object ev = ctx.evaluateString(scope, "'' + java.lang.System.getProperty(\"user.name\")", "exec", 0, null);
        System.out.println(ev);
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

Run fine on JVM Oracle 1.7.0_55 and do this on JVM Oracle 1.8.0_31 :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:1572)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:341)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:300)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.impl.ClassDescriptor.<init>(ClassDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.impl.ClassDescriptor.getInstance(ClassDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.impl.MethodDescriptor.getInstance(MethodDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.java.lang.reflect._Method.isVarArgs(_Method.java:96)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.jdk15.VMBridge_jdk15.isVarArgs(VMBridge_jdk15.java:33)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.init(MemberBox.java:44)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.<init>(MemberBox.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.reflect(JavaMembers.java:455)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.<init>(JavaMembers.java:43)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.lookupClass(JavaMembers.java:807)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.initMembers(NativeJavaObject.java:54)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:44)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:34)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrapAsJavaObject(WrapFactory.java:115)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrap(WrapFactory.java:72)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:236)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.exec_1._c_script_0(exec:0)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.exec_1.call(exec)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.exec_1.call(exec)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.exec_1.exec(exec)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1079)
    at RhinoOn8.main(RhinoOn8.java:12)
```

I tried with Rhino1.7R4 and Rhino1.7R5pre with the same result.

Someone knows a workaround (wihtout changing JS sources) ?

Comment: Shouldn't it use Nashorn in JDK8? Is there a reason to use Rhino?

Comment: This is for a webapp that should run on several java versions.

Comment: I just tried it with [Rhino1.7R4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7R4) and 64-bit JDK 1.8.0_31 on Windows 7, and it worked.

Comment: I am on a Linux 64 bit using a 32 bit JVM. I'll try on other OS to see.

Comment: Same bug on Windows 8.1 64 and the 1.8.0_31 32 bit JVM.

Comment: It's a good thing to use the ScriptEngine, so I have to port my code, but I have a problem to stack scopes (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212121/java-scriptengine-nashorn-rhino-how-to-stack-scopes-bindings)

Comment: New element, I used js-14.jar (jdk 1.4 compatibility). With the js.jar, it seems ok. I'll do extra tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **js.jar**, **not** the **js-14.jar** needed by the JVM 1.4.