# Java ScriptEngine (nashorn & rhino) : how to stack scopes / bindings?

Tags: java, rhino, nashorn, scriptengine, javax.script

I have to port a software using **Rhino1.7R4** and its **org.mozilla.javascript** package to use the **javax.script** package and its ScriptEngine (**Rhino** in Java 6 & 7, **Nashorn** in Java 8).

The main problem is to stack scopes (Bindings).
Using the Rhino jar, I do:

```
Scriptable scope ...
Scriptable newScope = javascriptContext.initStandardObjects();
newScope.setParentScope(scope);
```

So

- if a variable is defined without var, it's a global variable (root scope)
- if a variable is defined with var, it's a local variable (current scope)
- if a variable is accessed or modified, engine lookup in its current scope, and parent, and grand parent ... and the global scope

This is the JS standard behavior.

How can I do the same as **setParentScope** with javax.script API ?

Answer (score 1):

None of the `javax.script.Bindings` implementations I can find in my JDK has any sort of recursive lookup.  I think your only option would be to write a custom `Bindings` implementation which can fall back to the parent `Bindings`.

Edit: under Nashorn only (not Rhino, sorry), I think `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror` may be more capable, since it has `setProto()` to change the prototype object.  More about `ScriptObjectMirror` here: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes

Comment: The API is not sufficient. It is not known if a value assignment to a variable is global or local (with or without the "var" keyword for his statement).